# PHP 301 Redirect for Wordpress

Tags: php, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm totally newbie in this. I'd like to 301 redirect a Wordpress site to a new domain. Which `.php` file should I add the redirect code to? I was thinking it could be `index.php`?

Comment: Well better would be apply rewrite rules to **.htaccess** file.

Comment: [Ask Google before you ask here](https://www.google.com.bd/search?newwindow=1&rlz=1C1KMZB_enBD539BD539&espv=210&es_sm=122&q=wordpress+301+redirect+to+new+site+htaccess&oq=wordpress+301+redirect+to+new+site+htaccess&gs_l=serp.3...388426.391907.0.392482.14.14.0.0.0.0.213.1493.8j2j4.14.0....0...1c.1.38.serp..10.4.295.fkhNcZRSE2Y).

Comment: I asked specifically about PHP redirect.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to redirect it from php, then do this in index.php:

```
<?php
  header('Location: http://www.example.com');
?>
```

However, as Rahil Wazir suggested, you should considering doing it at Apache level.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually send the 301 header along with it's moved-to location.

```
<?php
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
header("Location: http://www.example.org/");
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

## How to do it in PHP

```
header("Location: http://someother.domain/place", true, 301); exit();
```

...says *"Replace all previous similar headers(`true`) and redirect to `http://someother.domain/place` with a status code of permanent redirect (`301`)"* - this is the pure-PHP "[header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)" way...

If you want to go the WordPress way, you can use [`wp_redirect( $location, $status );`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect)

```
wp_redirect( 'http://someother.domain/place', 301 ); exit();
```

...which basicly does the same thing (+some filters +sanitizes location)...

### Any way you choose => do `exit();` afterwards!

...otherwise it might not work :-) (especially the `wp_redirect(...)`)

## Where to put it in WordPress

index.php is definitely the **wrong** place - it could be replaced by any update...

The right place & way is to hook/add action to the action called <del>[`template_redirect`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)</del> [**`pre_get_posts`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts),

**EDIT:** I found out that `template_redirect` is *sometimes* too late beacuse *sometimes* WordPress rewrites the URL itself just before that action - WordPress tries to "guess" the target url, if the requested url is similar to an existing one... - you should decide, whether or not you need this feature and choose the action accordingly...

...If you don't want that feature, it may be better to use [**`pre_get_posts`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts),

which basically means "As Soon As Possible"

you would put the code **inside your theme's [`functions.php`](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/theme-functions/)** file...

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', function(){
   //do the redirect here
});
```

Though `template_redirect` action is only for the **front**-end,
`pre_get_posts` should be for both - ***front&&back***-end :-)

PS: You might want to fire the redirect in some more specific stage:

Just search for the right WordPress [Action](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).